# Algorithm for proper drawing of cosine function

Tags: sampling, 2d-graphics

I am working with the cosine function with a very large input, like `cos(a* t)`, where `t` varies between  `1` and `~ 200`; and `a` can be as large as `10^8`-

I come across, as expected, the artifact error. If I sample `t` with a stepsize of `0.01` with `a` 100, I get a plot like this :

[image]

Notice, that for large value of `a`, the sampling of `t` needs to be fine, otherwise, you will not get regular cosine shape from `-1` to `1`. Sometimes, wave peaks, and other times wave troughs will be missed, due to low granularity, and you will end up with a different shape of the wave than the theoritical value.

Now, increase `a` to be `100000`, and as expected, the effect is much more pronounced.

[image]

My question : Is there a formula / algorithm, to avoid this effect? Is there a formula, that tells you the correct step size for a large value of `a` ?

I tried to google the following keywords : `large input cosine function computer graphics`, but that did not help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in fact a way to avoid this effect and it is outlined by the NYQUIST sampling theorem - which states that the sampling rate should be at least twice as high as the maximum frequency of the function of interest. 
In this case where `cos(a * t)` is the function of interest, the frequency is `a/(2*pi)` - therefore your sampling rate should be greater than `2 * a/(2*pi)` (in this case you may even want the sampling rate to be even higher so that the cosine function has a nice curve to it). 
To get the step size from this sampling rate just use `t = 1/(sampling rate)` 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you! made my day! i knew of this in audio processing, but couldnt build the cnnection! you are a hero!